# Akka Streams - Creating a Flow which emits from a source when an input is received

Tags: akka-stream, akka-http

I have a `Source` that provides elements of type A.

And I have a `Flow` that receives elements of type B.

What I would like to do, is when the flow receives an input, the next element from the source is emitted as the output of the flow.

The way I do this currently, is I have the source connected to a `Sink.queue`. Then for each element in the flow, I map over it, discarding the input, and pulling the next value from the queue. Once the queue is empty, I complete the flow.

I feel like there ought to be a simpler way that I'm missing. That there is probably some built in mechanism to allow a input to trigger an element from a source.

For example:

```
val source = ... some akka streams source

val queue = source.grouped(limit.toInt).runWith(Sink.queue[Seq[DataFrame]])

Flow[Message]
  .prepend(Source.single(TextMessage.Strict("start")))
  .collect {
    case TextMessage.Strict(text) => Future.successful(text)
    case TextMessage.Streamed(textStream) => textStream.runFold("")(_ + _).flatMap(Future.successful)
  }
  // swallow the future of the incoming message's text
  .mapAsync(1)(identity)
  // take the next batch
  .mapAsync(1)(_ => queue.pull())
  // swallow the option monad, and add in an end or page-end message
  .collect {
  case Some(batch) if batch.size == limit => batch.toList :+ pageend
  case Some(batch) => batch.toList :+ end
  case None => List(end)
}
  // flatten out the frames
  .mapConcat(identity)
```

`end` and `pageend` are just special frames that the ui uses. The key part of the question is around this use of a queue.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code?

Comment: Yeah, I also have hard time understanding the goal here. Could you please give us schematic code of what you want to achieve ?